# Render depth, vector and normals without rendering RGB

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-map

I've rendered RGB images from a set of blend files and now I want to generate depth maps, normals and speed vectors from the blend files. Since generating these takes much lesser time as compared to rendering RGB images, is it possible to generate depth maps without having to render the RGB images?

PS: I'm using cycles rendering engine, since Eevee does not support speed vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm... I don't see direct option. So just a two tips ...

1. You could render *dept/vector/normal* directly with RGB as passes into **OpenEXR  Multilayer**

... or let **Compositor** save a render as separate files) so no extra rendering.

[image]

2. If you have already RGB rendered, set *Render Properties >* **Max Samples 1** for rendering *dept/vector/normal* passes.

[image]
(additionally you can try turn off Denoise, under *Light Paths* set *Max Bounces* to zero, *Caustics* if used, or disable all lights in scene and environment, but I didn't notice difference on my simple scene)

Comment: Yeah. Currently I'm setting max samples to 1. I was hoping there would be a better way :)

Comment: Yeah ... I thought pass "Combined" could do that job, but no :) So if no one smarter ...